# When I update Android RecyclerView with new items, old views are briefly shown before new views override them

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have the following code in my adapter:

```
   private val items: MutableList<T>
   open fun setItems(items: List<T>?) {
        this.items.clear()
        if (items != null)
            this.items.addAll(items)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

When corresponding RecyclerView is shown for the 1st time it is filled with views from the data I get from the network as expected.
When I request new data from the network, I make the recycler view visibility = gone and request data. When I get new network data and update the adapter using setItems() above, I make the recycler view visible again. The problem is that while the screen gets updated with the new views as expected, I get a brief "flash" showing the old views just before the new views are shown. I can fix it by calling recyclerView.removeAllViews() before setItems but is there a better way to handle it? I'm not sure what is the root cause here and the only idea I have is that notifyDataSetChanged is too slow to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are setting the RecyclerView's visibility to gone prior to calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. According to the documentation on `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

> LayoutManagers will be forced to fully rebind and relayout all
>   **visible** views. RecyclerView will attempt to synthesize **visible**
>   structural change events for adapters that report that they have
>   stable IDs when this method is used.

To work around this, you can just clear your recycler view items while your data is loading, and update it once data is loaded. This way you don't have to manipulate the recycler view's visibility.

Also, to improve performance, you should consider using more specific change events in your adapter:

```
   private val items: MutableList<T>
   open fun setItems(items: List<T>?) {
        clearItems()
        val newSize = items.size
        if (items != null)
            this.items.addAll(items)
        notifyItemRangeInserted(0, newSize)
    } 

    fun clearItems() {
        val oldSize = this.items.size
        this.items.clear()
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, oldSize)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, visibility was the root cause and performance did improve as you suggested.

Comment: @alexbtr No problem! Glad to help